# Atlantis Error when using with terragrunt

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt, atlantis

I am trying to create a GitOps with Terraform, Terragrunt and Atlantis. I have launched atlantis manually on a server.

In my `terragrunt` repo

I have `atlantis.yaml`

```
version: 3
automerge: true
projects:
  - name: meetup--us-east-1--eks
    dir: meetup/us-east-1/eks
    workflow: terragrunt
    terraform_version: v1.3.6
    autoplan:
      when_modified:
        - '**/**'
  - name: meetup--us-east-1--vpc
    dir: meetup/us-east-1/vpc
    workflow: terragrunt    
    terraform_version: v1.3.6
    autoplan:
      when_modified:
        - '**/**'
```

In the same `terragrunt` repo I have one more file called `repo.yaml` where i defined my `terragrunt` workflow

```
- id: github.com/samrepos/*
  workflow: terragrunt
  allowed_overrides: [workflow]
  allowed_workflows: [terragrunt]
  allow_custom_workflows: false
workflows:
  terragrunt:
    plan:
      steps:
        - run: TERRAGRUNT_TFPATH=terraform$ATLANTIS_TERRAFORM_VERSION terragrunt plan -no-color -out $PLANFILE
    apply:
      steps:
        - run: TERRAGRUNT_TFPATH=terraform$ATLANTIS_TERRAFORM_VERSION terragrunt apply -no-color $PLANFILE
```

I am launching atlantis using

```
atlantis server --atlantis-url="http://10.0.0.17" --gh-user="samrepos" --gh-token="123" --gh-webhook-secret="123" --repo-allowlist="github.com/samrepos/terragrunt" --config=atlantis.yaml
```

my `atlantis.yaml` that I am using to launch Atlantis

```
repos:
- id: github.com/samrepos/*
  workflow: terragrunt
  allowed_overrides: [workflow]
  allowed_workflows: [terragrunt]
  allow_custom_workflows: false
workflows:
  terragrunt:
    plan:
      steps:
        - run: TERRAGRUNT_TFPATH=terraform$ATLANTIS_TERRAFORM_VERSION terragrunt plan -no-color -out $PLANFILE
    apply:
      steps:
        - run: TERRAGRUNT_TFPATH=terraform$ATLANTIS_TERRAFORM_VERSION terragrunt apply -no-color $PLANFILE
```

I am getting this error

```
{"level":"error","ts":"2023-11-14T20:37:32.385Z","caller":"events/pull_updater.go:17","msg":"parsing atlantis.yaml: repo config not allowed to set 'workflow' key: server-side config needs 'allowed_overrides: [workflow]'","json":{"repo":"samrepos/terragrunt","pull":"12"},"stacktrace":"github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/server/events.(*PullUpdater).updatePull\n\t/home/runner/work/atlantis/atlantis/server/events/pull_updater.go:17\ngithub.com/runatlantis/atlantis/server/events.(*PlanCommandRunner).run\n\t/home/runner/work/atlantis/atlantis/server/events/plan_command_runner.go:199\ngithub.com/runatlantis/atlantis/server/events.(*PlanCommandRunner).Run\n\t/home/runner/work/atlantis/atlantis/server/events/plan_command_runner.go:292\ngithub.com/runatlantis/atlantis/server/events.(*DefaultCommandRunner).RunCommentCommand\n\t/home/runner/work/atlantis/atlantis/server/events/command_runner.go:328"}
```

Comment: How are you specifying atlantis to use that config file? Keep in mind allowing workflow overrides allows any contributors to that repository to execute arbitrary code on your atlantis server.